# jquery dialog upgrade from 1.8.2 to 1.9.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am in the process of upgrading my application from jquery 1.8.2 to 1.9.1. So I have included the 1.9.1 dll and included the Themes.css to my master page. When I pop up a dialog box the buttons do not have any text for the buttons. In 1.8.2 the dialog has a Yes and No button. Now I get buttons with no text.

This is the code for the dialog. Is this where the problem is?

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
resizable: false,
height: 140,
modal: true,
buttons: {
    'No': function () {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("close");
        },
    'Yes': function () {
        $("#lblErrors").text("");
        $("#lblMessage").text("");
        $('#btnAddNewCourse').show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code in Fiddle with jQuery 1.9.1, it looks like it should still be a valid way of writing the dialog: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Reedpm2/L9qnyrz6/1/)

You could also try writing your dialog code in this syntax:

`$( ".selector" ).dialog({
  buttons: [ { text: "Ok", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } } ]
});`

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Reedpm2/yzdef2vd/1/)

If re-writing doesn't seem to fix it make sure you aren't getting any errors and that your scripts are included in the right order.

Comment: Did you add jquery migrate ? [link] https://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/04/jquery-1-9-1-released/

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a version of the themes 1.9.2 and that seemed to resolve the issue. Thank you.